# Angular 2 Routing with Home Page

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I am learning Angular2 Routing and try to display the Welcome Page.
My app has three pages

- Welcome Page (it's just a blank page with just links to other Routes)
- Home Page - Some texts and Description
- Todo List Page - List of ToDos

The problem is that I cannot manage to display the Welcome Page.  It automatically loads Home page and show the content from the HomeComponent by default.

As shown in the screenshot, I want to display only 2 links.  I want to load the content from Home/Todo only when it is clicked.  But by default, it goes to localhost:xxx/Home and load the Home page.

[image]

I tried to set the '' blank path to AppComponent as below, but it loads AppComponent twice and shows the links two times.

```
{ path: '', component: AppComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
```

**app.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        HttpModule,
        RouterModule.forRoot([
            { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
            { path: 'todo', component: TodoListComponent },
            { path: '**', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' }
        ])
    ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        HomeComponent,
        TodoListComponent
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core"

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'app',
    template: `
    <div>
        <nav class='navbar navbar-default'>
            <div class='container-fluid'>
                <a class='navbar-brand'>{{pageTitle}}</a>
                <ul class='nav navbar-nav'>
                    <li><a [routerLink]="['/home']">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a [routerLink]="['/todo']">To Do</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>        
     </div>
    <div class='container'>
            <router-outlet></router-outlet>
        </div>
     `
})
export class AppComponent {    
}
```

**home/home.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,    
    templateUrl: "home.component.html"    
})
export class HomeComponent {
}
```

**home/home.component.html**

```
<h1>Hello from Home Component</h1>
<h2>This is my first TODO App for Angular 2...</h2>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the reason the `HomeComponent` is being displayed is because your `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` will change the underlying component with `home` when the url is /home. You also have this line in your app.module.ts

`{ path: '**', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' }`,

which means that all of your urls that do not match `/home` or `/todo` will make your `HomeComponent` pop up. You could try to remove the redirecting:

`{ path: '**', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' }`
or redirect to `''` instead (or a new `PageNotFoundComponent`).

Also make sure that none of the items (home or todo) in your menu is selected on page load.

Answer (score 10):

you need to remove this line 
{ path: '**', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' }

what you mention in the above line is

if any url other that /home or /todo comes please redirectTo to /home. So that it always display Home.

So your app.module.ts should be

```js
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
      { path: 'todo', component: TodoListComponent },
      { path: '**', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' }
    ])
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    TodoListComponent
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

This will fix the issue. I tried and it got fixed
[image: ScreenShot]

check the below link for using routing in angular 2
http://www.angularinfo.com/routings/